# Cascading Dropdown with multiselect options

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dropdown, checkboxlist

I built my cascading  dropdown  with three options , i need to have  the second one with multiple  choice but if i put multiple on , it's so ugly so can i some one help me  to have one nice , i do it  on wordpress but i generate  all with this script

```js
var subjectObject = {
  "Front-end": {
    "HTML": ["Links", "Images", "Tables", "Lists"],
    "CSS": ["Borders", "Margins", "Backgrounds", "Float"],
    "JavaScript": ["Variables", "Operators", "Functions", "Conditions"]    
  },
  "Back-end": {
    "PHP": ["Variables", "Strings", "Arrays"],
    "SQL": ["SELECT", "UPDATE", "DELETE"]
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  var subjectSel = document.getElementById("subject");
  var topicSel = document.getElementById("topic");
  var chapterSel = document.getElementById("chapter");
  for (var x in subjectObject) {
    subjectSel.options[subjectSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
  }
  subjectSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters- and Topics- dropdowns
    chapterSel.length = 1;
    topicSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
      topicSel.options[topicSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
    }
  }
  topicSel.onchange = function() {
    //empty Chapters dropdown
    chapterSel.length = 1;
    //display correct values
    var z = subjectObject[subjectSel.value][this.value];
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
      chapterSel.options[chapterSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
Subjects: <select name="subject" id="subject">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select subject</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
 
Topics: <select name="topic" id="topic" multiple>
    <option value="" selected="selected"  >Please select subject first</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
Chapters: <select name="chapter" id="chapter">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Please select topic first</option>
  </select>
```

I want to have this  solution but  i can't make it  maybe  because the list is generated by JS .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OvUsN.png)

Comment: There are numerous select replacement scripts you can use that let you use things like checkboxes in the dropdown

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not so clear to me , i'm not an expert on JS  also ! sorry@charl

Comment: An example would be the script named *select2* another is *chosen* and there are others as well

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks one more time , how can i add  select2 , i tried  but it does'nt work , maybe i must change something  on the script  which load  the options  of second list.?? 

https://select2.org/getting-started/installation